# How do I load values from a .json file into a Devops Yaml Pipeline Parameter

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Microsoft Documentation explains the use of parameters in Yaml Pipeline jobs as

```
# File: azure-pipelines.yml
trigger:
- master

extends:
    template: simple-param.yml
    parameters:
        yesNo: false # set to a non-boolean value to have the build fail
```

But instead of statically specifying the value of yesNo: I'd prefer to load it from a completely separate json config file. Preferably a json file that both my Build Job and my Application could share so that parameters specified for the Application could also be used in the Build Job.

Thus the question:
How do I load values from a .json file into a Devops Yaml Pipeline Parameter?

Comment: and yes Im aware I can completely bypass Yaml and if anyone wants to suggest a way to do that while still passing the parameters to single-param.yml that would work provided I don't then also have to completely rewrite single-param.yml as a powershell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using this marketplace task:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OneLuckiDev.json2variable

And it's been working great so far. Haven't tried it builds, but can't see why it wouldn't work with separate build pipelines/multi-staged builds. There are a few things you have to be aware of/stumble upon, like double escaping slashes in directory paths - and you'll have to fetch secrets from someplace else, like traditional variable groups.

Comment: To clarify: we have separate json-config files stored alongside solutions in version control, and we bundle them into build artifacts, where they are then read into releases, where they function as release variables. We use Colin's tokenizer and replace tokens tasks with them: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=colinsalmcorner.colinsalmcorner-buildtasks

Comment: So spent the last couple days trying this approach. Json2Variable does read the config and copy in the values so if you just need a few settings this would work. So Ive accepted the answer. However our needs are more complex. I need to read in a Collection of Objects each with a set of values that we iterate over. json2Variable doesn't really work well for this it flattens out the entire hierarchy into a list of name value pairs which makes iteration problematic. 
Guess Ill just write a console app to do what I need and execute it with a script: step.

Comment: Gotcha; we deal with quite simple confiugrations, so I've managed so far with that task. Wouldn't mind reading about solutions to more complex cases, if you have time to, for example, write a blog post somewhere about what you came up with.